# javascript Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': The provided selector is empty

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, queryselector

I get the error:

> Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': The provided selector is empty.

When I call the method for the second time and there on forwards when I use `this.#email = document.querySelector(this.#email).value` however when I use the parameter passed to the method as in `document.querySelector(email_input_id).value` everything works fine. I should add that the function is triggered by click event.

```
buttonClicked(email_input_id,passowrd_inpiut_id,password_repeat_input_id){
        this.clear_error_div();
        let email_input_id2 = this.#email;
        this.#email = document.querySelector(email_input_id2).value; // works first time only
        this.#password = document.querySelector(passowrd_inpiut_id).value; // works
        this.#password_repeat = document.querySelector(password_repeat_input_id).value; // works
        console.log(typeof this.#email);  // output is string
        console.log(typeof email_input_id); // output is string
        console.log(this.#email); // output is #email_inp
        console.log(email_input_id); // output is #email_inp
        //this.#email = document.querySelector(this.#email).value; // first time only then error
        // this.#password = document.querySelector(this.#password).value; // same
        // this.#password_repeat = document.querySelector(this.#password_repeat).value; // same
        this.#password_strength();
        this.#passwords_equality();
        this.#password_proper_length();
        this.#error_container.innerHTML += this.error_message;
        
        return this.#password_email_okay();
        for (var key in this.errors) {
            var value = errors[key];
            console.log(key + " = " + value + '');
        }
    }
```

I've tried logging everything, I'm stuck as stated.

Comment: im fine passing parameters, but i would love to know why it works when the passed in value ie the string is the exact same

Comment: i now know that it is in fact empty upon recalling, but i wonder why? its never resigned to empty. its still the same instance of the class. I would love to learn if any one is kind enough to teach on this circumstance.

Comment: im very stupid sorry, ofcourse im reassigning. i am at this.#email = document.querySelector(email_input_id2).value;

Answer (score 0):

On the first occasion it works, but there on after it doesn't because I've in fact reassigned. Fixed code is below:

```
 buttonClicked(){
    this.clear_error_div();
    console.log(typeof this.#email_id);
    console.log(this.#email_id);
    this.#email_value = document.querySelector(this.#email_id).value;
    this.#password_value = document.querySelector(this.#password_id).value;
    this.#password_repeat_value = document.querySelector(this.#password_repeat_id).value;
    this.#password_strength();
    this.#passwords_equality();
    this.#password_proper_length();
    this.#error_container.innerHTML += this.error_message;
    
    return this.#password_email_okay();
    for (var key in this.errors) {
        var value = errors[key];
        console.log(key + " = " + value + '');
    }
}
```